# How to do a division without "/"?

Tags: c++, recursion

PROBLEM 2:  Consider a finite set S with n elements; the number of distinct subsets of S with exactly two is called "n choose 2" and typically written as n/2.  You may Recall that n/2=(n(n-1))/2.

Below is a (trivial) C++ function which takes a non-negative integer n and returns n/2 (also a non-negative integer):

```
unsigned int n_choose_2(unsigned int n) {
    if(n==0) 
       return 0;
    else 
       return n*(n-1)/2;
 }
```

Your job:  write a function which also returns n/2 but with the following constraints:

- You cannot use the multiplication operator `*`
- You cannot use the division operator `/`
- You cannot have any loops
- You cannot add any additional parameters to the function
- Your function must be self-contained:  no helper functions!
- You cannot use any globals
- You cannot use any static variables
- You cannot use any "bit twiddling" operations -- no shifts, etc.

However:

- You can use recursion
- You can use the `+` and `-` operators.

This is what I got, need help to avoid using `/` and check if I'm in the correct way.

```
unsigned int n_choose_2(unsigned int n) {
    if(n==0) 
         return 0;
    else 
         return n_choose_2(n)/2 - n/2;
}
```

Comment: A hint: If your recursive call passes the same argument(s) it received, unmodified, you've just written the recursive equivalent of an infinite loop (except it will stop when you overflow the stack).

Comment: You can use bit shift specifically for case of dividing by powers of 2 (although behaviour is undefined/uspecified if the shift exceeds number of bits in the variable).  More generally, `log(a/b) = log(a) - log(b)`,   so `exp(log(a) - log(b)) == a/b`  (assuming `a` and `b` non-zero).    Either way, better off using division - the compiler will do the transformation if needed, and is probably less error prone than humans in doing that.

Comment: Another hint: You don't need to do division at all. Either `n` or `n - 1` is guaranteed to be even, so if you use only half of it in your virtual multiplication (e.g. by adding/subtracting 2 to approach its limit, not 1), then you got the division by 2 for free.

Comment: @Peter: Per the instructions "You cannot use any 'bit twiddling' operations -- no shifts, etc."

Comment: @ShadowRanger I changed to return n_choose_2(n - 1) - (n - 1) + 2; but get 0, 2, 3, 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is all the hint you need.  You're trying to compute `(n*(n-1))/2`

let's work with an **unacceptable** but functional solution to print out the first set of numbers.

```
for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++)
{
    std::cout << "n_choose_2(" << n << "):  " << (n * (n-1)) / 2 << std::endl;
}
```

Of course you can't submit that, because it uses the forbidden math operation. But let's see what it prints out:

```
n_choose_2(0):  0
n_choose_2(1):  0
n_choose_2(2):  1
n_choose_2(3):  3
n_choose_2(4):  6
n_choose_2(5):  10
n_choose_2(6):  15
n_choose_2(7):  21
n_choose_2(8):  28
n_choose_2(9):  36
n_choose_2(10):  45
n_choose_2(11):  55
n_choose_2(12):  66
n_choose_2(13):  78
n_choose_2(14):  91
n_choose_2(15):  105
n_choose_2(16):  120
n_choose_2(17):  136
n_choose_2(18):  153
n_choose_2(19):  171
```

Now look at the amount each line increments by.

Take any two adjacent lines (except the first pair) and subtract the difference.  For example, `n_choose_2(10)` is 45 and `n_choose_2(9)` is 36.  `n_choose_2(10) - n_choose_2(9) == 9`.

`n_choose_2(19) - n_choose_2(18)`  is the same as `171 - 153` which is `18`.

**Notice the pattern?**

Here's all you need:

```
unsigned int n_choose_2(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // WHAT COMES NEXT IS UP TO YOU....
}
```

Comment: @l4m2 - Nope.  I just inserted the terminating condition. The *cough cough* recursion  *cough cough* is up to the OP to insert.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: @CarAndre - if this answer works for you, do not forget to "accept" it and give it a green check mark.